Confusion about what first-order theory is
What is theory exactly in first-order logic? For example, when I read the definition of completeness theorem ([1]):

The completeness theorem applies to any first-order theory: If T is such a theory, and φ is a sentence (in the same language) and every model of T is a model of φ, then there is a (first-order) proof of φ using the statements of T as axioms.

-- it sounds like T is a set of axioms -- "using the statements of T as axioms".
In the following discussion both answers say that "[first-order theory] is closed with respect to logical derivations".
So it seems like in the first case a theory is some initial set of truths e.g. $T = \{AX_1, AX_2, AX_3\}$, whilst in the second case it is a set of all the truths derived from and including those initial truths -- $T=[\{x: x=D(T)\} \lor T_0]$ where $T_0 = \{AX_1, AX_2, AX_3\}$ and $D(T)$ -- is a function that logically derives a theorem from T that is not in T.

Yes, in this case it is a collection pf axioms: the axioms for geometry, for arithmetic, for set theory.

Closed wrt logical derivation means that the axioms are "on top" of predicate calculus: logical axioms+rules of inference.

Some people require deductive closure and others don't. The discussion at the post is indeed a bit misleading in how strongly it suggests that deductive closure is always part of the definition of a theory. At the end of the day, this convention doesn't actually affect much - it just means you sometimes have to replace "$\varphi \in T$" by "$T \vdash \varphi$". Does this answer your question for example?

You can think of a theory as a set of axioms, or as any set $S$ of statements which is consistent and closed under deduction - that is, any statement which can be deduced from $S$ is already in $S.$ You can think of $S$ as the closure of some set of axioms.

Often, it is easier to think in terms of axioms - we often have a hard time classifying membership in $S.$

@IzaakvanDongen I think it does, this is what I used to do somewhat intuitively, but lately I started to feel that I am eyeballing a bit too much so decided to pin this down exactly :)
